# La construction « être frustré parce que » est-elle correcte?

Tags: formulation-idiomatique, constructions, formulation, reformulation

Exemple avec trois énonciations différentes en fin de phrase.

> Il est frustré parce que ses commentaires constructifs n’ont pas été pris en considération à plusieurs occasions.

> Il est frustré parce que ses commentaires constructifs sont demeurés sans réponse à plusieurs occasions.

> Il est frustré parce que ses commentaires constructifs ont été délibérément ignorés à plusieurs occasions.

N’hésitez pas à me proposer d’autres tournures (plus élégantes) si vous jugez qu’il en serait mieux ainsi. J’aime avoir des points de vue différents sur une phrase, ils me permettent de perfectionner mon expression dans la mesure où ce qui est présenté (c’est souvent le cas) est meilleur, d’ouvrir de nouveaux horizons à l’esprit en l’occurrence le mien et d’élargir le cercle de mes connaissances en français sur tous les plans (grammaire, structure, orthographe, vocabulaire).

Edit.

Voici une composition (phrase toute faite **en gras** plus ajout *en italique*) de dernière minute qui m’a traversé l’esprit:

> **Il a été frustré dans son espérance**: *ses commentaires constructifs sont restés sans réponse à plusieurs occasions.*

> **Il a été frustré dans son espérance** *parce que ses commentaires constructifs sont restés sans réponse à plusieurs occasions.*

http://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9F1807

Remarque:

Il est possible que, dans mes exemples, j’emploie des mots pour d’autres, ce qui est souvent le cas d’ailleurs quand j’écris et c’est d’autant plus vrai lorsque des émotions, des sentiments et des états d’esprit sont en jeu (peut-être suis-je atteint d’alexithymie, un déficit de l’affect, qu’en sais-je: un diagnostic se fait toujours attendre). Dans le contexte, j’emploie « frustré » mais ce terme n’est peut-être pas le plus pertinent. Si c’est le cas, vous n’avez qu’à m’aiguiller sur le mot qui cadrerait le mieux dans la phrase. Certains contributeurs ont, selon mes plus récentes observations, la force d’esprit de sonder mon âme et de trouver le mot juste qui rend l’idée que je cherche à exprimer. De vrais télépathes à la rescousse d’un psychopathe , c’est tout à leur honneur et je leur en suis fort reconnaissant! Sur ce, laissez aller votre fantaisie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Être frustré* dans le sens d'« être déçu » peut être suivi de l'objet de la frustration : « je suis frustré dans mon plaisir d'aller à ce concert », ou d'une subordonnée qui donne une explication : « je suis frustré parce que le concert a été annulé ».  On peut très bien combiner les deux « je suis frustré **dans** mon espérance **parce que** mes commentaires sont restés sans réponse ». Ajouter l'objet de la frustration donne une indication supplémentaire, c'est tout.

Par contre les trois formulations différentes en fin de phrase n'expriment pas la même chose. Nous avons trois constructions au passif, ce qui permet de ne pas exprimer l'agent (le sujet réel). C'est le choix du verbe qui permet d'exprimer la façon dont le locuteur a perçu le rôle de l'agent.

1.

> ses commentaires sont **demeurés sans réponse** à plusieurs occasions.

Il n'est question que des commentaires, on ne sait pas pourquoi ils n'ont pas reçu de réponses, il n'y a pas d'agent impliqué. On peut penser que s'il n'y a pas eu de réponses c'est tout aussi bien parce que ces commentaires étaient mal exprimés ou parce que personne n'a eu l'occasion de les lire.

2.

> ses commentaires n’ont pas été **pris en considération** à plusieurs occasions.

Ici l'agent est nommé de façon implicite : le locuteur pense que des personnes ont lu ces commentaires mais aussi que personne n'en a tenu compte ou n'a pris le temps d'y réfléchir, mais la raison n'est pas évoquée (manque de temps, pas jugé utile...).

3.

> ses commentaires ont été délibérément ignorés à plusieurs occasions.

La différence avec la formulation précédente ne réside pas entre **ne pas prendre en considération** et **ignorer**, qui sont ici presque synonymes, mais dans l'emploi de **délibérément** qui permet au locuteur de porter un jugement négatif sur les personnes auxquelles ces commentaires ont été destinés : il reproche à ces personnes la volonté (contenue dans « délibérément ») de ne pas prendre en compte sa parole.

---

Answer (score -4):

« Frustré parce que » pourrait être considéré comme une tournure qui a récemment commencé à être utilisée (1950) ;

[image]

[ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=frustr%C3%A9+parce+que&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfrustr%C3%A9%20parce%20que%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cfrustr%C3%A9%20parce%20que%3B%2Cc0), [page d'exemples](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22frustr%C3%A9%20parce%20que%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)

dernièrement elle a commencé à jouir d'une faveur qui monte en flèche. Il n'y a apparemment pas de problème à l'utiliser. Mais en réalité on ne devrait voir dans cette construction qu'un assemblage libre. Ce qui est innovatif c'est la création d'un nouvel usage qui n'a pas été retenu dans le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/frustrer) ; jusqu'à une période récente, ce verbe, au passif, faisait partie d'une famille d'expressions idiomatiques, "*frustrer qqn **dans qqc***".

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/frustrer)) **B.** − P. ext. Décevoir.
> ♦ Gaspard (...) cherchait déjà quelque moyen honnête de frustrer l'espérance de tous ses créanciers.  (Sandeau, Sacs,1851, p. 27)
> − **Frustrer qqn dans**.Frustrer qqn dans son espoir, dans son attente (De Gaulle).
> Au passif.
> ♦ Frustré dans ses ambitions, du moins entendait-il vivre à sa guise, et, n'ayant pas su plaire, il s'essayait discrètement à déplaire. (France, Orme,1897, p. 70)
> ♦ Les notables qui avaient négocié avec Murphy l'avènement manqué de Giraud se trouvaient frustrés dans leurs espoirs.  (De Gaulle, Mém. guerre,1956, p. 64)

Alors que dans le  passé on disait « Untel a été frustré *dans* ses ambitions », par exemple, on dit maintenant aussi « Untel a été frustré parce que ses ambitions ont été supprimées, réprimées, *parce que* ses ambitions lui ont été retirées, etc ». Le remplacement de la tournure prépositionnelle par une conjonctive introduite par « parce que » marque un passage de l'assertion d'une déception *relative* à une situation implicite à celle que la situation explicite correspondante  *est la cause* d'une déception. C'est une possibilité acceptable à mon avis.

Les trois phrases constituent un crescendo  d'incrimination dans le domaine de la négligence, passant, d'une assertion de désintérêt banal, à l'assertion d'un manque de considération dans des circonstances qui semblaient demander une réaction alors que les intéressés ne se sont aucunement  manifestés, à finalement   celle d'une ignorance totale par fait de malveillance caractérisée.  En cela, les idées dans chacune d'elles sont différentes. Leur style ne peut pas être incriminé, des changements ne seraient que question de préférence personnelles.

---

> Il a été frustré dans son espérance : ses commentaires constructifs sont restés sans réponse à plusieurs occasions.
>
> Il a été frustré dans son espérance parce que ses commentaires constructifs sont restés sans réponse à plusieurs occasions.

Dans cette première phrase du second groupe, la proposition introduite par le deux-points est une explication de l'espérance et donc on trouve dans la phrase entière un usage traditionnel du verbe  « frustrer ». Il n'y a rien à dire, tout au moins, c'est ce qu'il me semble. Toujours à mon avis, il n'en serait pas de même pour la seconde ; la raison que j'entrevois est simple : la nouvelle tournure avec « parce que » empiète sur la tournure traditionnelle (qu'il me semble ne pas falloir rejeter) et le résultat est cacophonique ; la conjonctive est-elle une explication de l'espérance ou bien l'espérance est-elle autre et la conjonctive l'assertion d'une cause connexe ? On se dépêtrera de ce petit embrouillamini grâce au contexte, bien sûr, mais doit-on tolérer de telles constructions hybrides qui dérangent l'harmonie ? Je ne le crois pas, c'est une question de style, et le style est une affaire de linguiste, une affaire de tout étudiant sérieux de le la langue.

Comment: J’ai donné un vote positif à votre réponse. À en juger par les votes négatifs auxquels vous êtes en bute, ou plutôt auxquels vos réponses sont souvent en proie, et ce malgré la pertinence de celles-ci, j’en suis venu à croire que quelques utilisateurs de la plateforme prennent plaisir à s’acharner contre vous et j’en suis navré.

Comment: @Jean-LouFrenette Je croyais bien savoir à qui je devais le vote positif précoce pour la présente réponse… Cette idée d'acharnement aveugle contre moi m'a déjà été communiquée par certaines personnes (deux ou trois), mais 
aucune ne l'a encore exprimée aussi nettement que vous. Ça se remarque donc… Il est réconfortant de voir que d'autres partagent ce point de vue, qui est aussi le mien. Je vous remercie de risquer ainsi, publiquement, vos opinions, et  je ne peux qu'admirer le courage que cela demande.

Comment: Correction: en butte.